# How to create contours from an IDW raster

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, contour, inverse-distance-weighted

I'm new to QGIS and am trying to create vector contours from this IDW raster. I followed [Ujaval Gandhi's "Interpolating Point Data" tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html) step by step but am not getting the same results for step 18.The first images is the IDW raster. The second is the contour vectors created from raster->extraction->contours which looks like it created a point for every pixel in the raster.

[image: IDW raster]
[image: contours vectors]

Comment: Please edit and add a link to: Ujaval Gandhi's "Interpolating Point Data"

Comment: Please clarify your question. The screenshots dont look like "a point for every pixel".

Comment: correction - duplicate of this question :  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155658/how-to-get-smooth-contours-from-points-or-idw-raster-in-qgis

Comment: @StevenKay It's not a duplicate it's a different question that needed different images.

Comment: @underdark the second image looks like a point for every pixel to me. it was created using raster->extraction->contour.

Comment: @dof1985 I can't add it to the post but here it is http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html

Comment: What contour interval did you specify? What is the range of values in the interpolated raster?

Comment: @whuber I used 10 for the contour interval. The values in the IDW raster range from 21017 - 113678. Here's a screenshot of the idw raster layer properties style http://imgur.com/668SzOD

Comment: That means you should be looking at 1+(113678 - 21017)/10 = over 9000 contour lines!  What does it look like when you set the interval to something more reasonable for this range, such as 10000?

Comment: @whuber that worked! thanks a lot. I wouldn't have thought to use an interval that high. All the tutorials I found used intervals between 5 and 10. I  don't understand how you came up with it though but at least I have a range to play around with.

Comment: Here's how I came up with it: a contour map will be readable and useful only when it contains between a few and a few dozen contour levels--roughly around 10.  Dividing the range by 10-1 = 9 gives very close to 10000 for the common difference between all contours. I don't use QGIS, but I would hope its interface would suggest a default contour interval using a similar rule--and that it would issue a warning when asked to generate a ridiculous number of contours (say, over 500 or so, which would allow only one or two pixels between contours on the screen).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26273/discussion-between-jisike-and-whuber).