# C/C++ function to return minimum set of points required to represent a geometric shape

Tags: grass-gis, geometry, qgis-processing, simplify

I am looking for a method from Grass, GEOS, or similar that will delete those points in a geometry which do not affect its shape.

**Example 1**

```
+----+----+
p0   p1   p2
```

*p1 can be deleted without affecting the shape of the line*

**Example 2**

```
   p0   p1
   +----+
   |     \
p4 +      \
   |       \
p3 +--------+ p2
```

*p4 can be deleted without affecting the shape of the polygon*

I am sure this has been asked/answered and there is probably a name for the output point set (akin to convex hull) but I am not sure what to search for.

It would be relatively straightforward (no pun intended) to write my own function but obviously silly if there is something out there already.

Comment: A simple Ramer-Douglas-Peucker with a *very* small tolerance will eliminate redundant vertices

Comment: The "generalize" or "simplify" tools of most GIS packages use RDP (previously known as Douglas-Peucker or Douglas-Poiker) see also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis