# Making building orthogonalized in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, polygon-creation, building

[image: The image shown below]

From the left polygon to right polygon, May I know how to achieve it by using QGIS?

I have tried the orthogonalized tool in QGIS, but there is no change in shape.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you use the tool? It could be that your input building is too messy, perhaps try simplifying them first https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/smoothing-generalizing-polygon-in-qgis then perhaps increase the iterations.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, thank you for your reply. I have tried the way you said, but the result is quite not satisfied. May I ask you about the Automated Feature Extraction from LiDAR Orthophoto? Is there any ways to do the AFE by using QGIS? The features that i wanna extract is Building, transportation, hydro and vegetation.  I have try the OTB tool and SCP working toolbar. And the output of polygon building and transportation is not in a smooth line. Is it I need to manual edit after the AFE?

Comment: I know very little about automated feature extraction and/or machine learning. Generally this site requires one question per post, if you want to ask about automated feature extraction in QGIS you will need to ask a new question.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, Alright thanks, will post a new question.

Comment: That's just a slightly shrinked oriented bouding box.

Comment: Or a convex hull

Answer (score 7):

Create the Oriented Bounding box of the polygon with the [Oriented minimum bounding box](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#oriented-minimum-bounding-box) tool or with QGIS expressions (use Geoemtry Generator or Geometry by expression) with this expression (see [`oriented_bbox()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#oriented-bbox)):

```
oriented_bbox ($geometry)
```

*Orange: initial polygon; blue: created by the expression above:*
[image]

---

**Variant: same area**

And, a bit more sophisticated, you can scale the resulting rectangle to get the same area as the input polygon:

```
with_variable (
    'scale',
    sqrt (area ($geometry) / area (oriented_bbox ($geometry))),
    scale( 
        oriented_bbox ($geometry),
        @scale,
        @scale
    )
)
```

*Blue polygon created by the expression has the same area as the initial orange polygon:*
[image]