# Ingesting .shp file in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-explorer

I'm trying to ingest a .shp file into my Google Earth Engine code editor, but it is giving an error message "File upload unsuccessful (Error: HTTP error error 500)" I know that this isn't a problem with the .shp file itself since I got the same error using another file I uploaded yesterday without issue. I am also uploading the other files needed (.dbf, .shx), and I even made another account using a different Google email address and still am facing the same issue. Are there any ideas out there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know ee has a vertice limit. I've run into that before where I couldn't upload the file due to exceeding it. Can you give us an indication of this? If you think this might be the culprit, [here's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/smoothing-generalizing-polygon-in-qgis) another post whose sought to simplify their geometry. And [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#simplify) is the QGIS link.

If that doesn't work, I would also suggest using QGIS's 'Repair Shapefile' function before uploading.

Comment: I don't think it is a vertice limit, the shp file is about 3.5 million rows long but it doesn't have any properties (just points, it's a grid over the geography) and so I don't want to simplify the geography here

Comment: That's a pretty big file. Have you tried to just upload a sample? Say, 1,000 rows?